# Backtesting benchmark / control test design

Tags: backtesting, benchmark

I am designing a backtesting system to test an algorithm.

I'd like to have a benchmark / control test results 
to compare to the results of a custom algorithm.

A limited "set" of stocks is selected to invest in.
The algorithm can choose to buy one or more stocks.

In an effort to have a benchmark to measure against, the backtest system can:

- Buy some or all of the stocks on the first day of the test period.
- Sell all of the positions of the set at the end of the test period.
- Include transaction fees and slippage costs during the test period.

To test the algorithm, the backtest system can:

- Allow the algorithm to choose to buy one or all stocks on the first
  test day.
- Loop the algorithm through time for until the last day of the testing
  period.
- Include similar transaction fees and slippage costs during the test
  period.

The profit percentage of the "set test" and "algo test" are recorded.

The "set test profit" is deducted from the "algo test profit" to rank the test.

QUESTION 1: **Should the algorithm be optimized to outperform the benchmark test** (rather than simply optimizing for the algorithm's profit)?

QUESTION 2:  **What test results should be compared?**

- A. Buying and selling the entire set VS. ALL the positions the algo
  bought.
- B. Buying and selling the entire set VS. EACH individual position the
  algo bought.[1]
- C. Buying and selling the set of stocks the blackbox bought VS. The
  algo results.
- D. Buying THE stock the algo bought for the position VS. the algo
  position result.

QUESTION 3:  **How should the profits of the tests be calculated?**

- A. Buying and selling all positions on both the "set test" and "algo
  test".[2]
- B. Buying and selling the "set test" VS. Allowing the algo to keep
  unsold stocks.
- C. Buying the set and selling stocks that end the algo test sold VS.
  algo results.

Comment: [1] The "position" can affect the results.

Comment: [2] It is somewhat difficult to force the algorithm to sell off all of it's positions at the end of the test period. For example, if the "test cash" provided for the test is low, Rule 431 may be triggered (and code would have to be written to deal with that issue).

Comment: To me, your description is unclear. Is your algorithm allow to update its position every day? intraday? only at the beginning of the test?

Comment: The algo is allowed to update positions daily. The "set test" is "buy and hold". Both tests use the same set of stocks.